# Combinatorial Block Designs in Statistics

Tags: hypothesis-testing, experiment-design, combinatorics

How are **combinatorial designs** such as BIBD and  Steiner triple systems used in statistics  in designs of experiments and hypothesis testing.

Comment: I would start with Combinatorics of Experimental Design (Oxford science publications) by  Combinatorics of Experimental Design (Oxford science publications)   an maybe ... (will a later) ...